# How is cross-origin animatable via javascript within an Svg or is this info false

Tags: javascript, svg, cross-domain, documentation

Not Sure whether this is a typo in the Article by who-ever created it or whether i'm reading it or misinterpreting it some how,
but as I was trying to learn more about SVG and specifically Scripts within SVG, came across this Document.
[Script Element in Svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/script) on [Mozilla's Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org) browsing through the document, it has a section that list's valid attributes for the SVG or Scripts, which are `crossorigin`, `href`, `type` & `xlink:href`, next to or inline with `crossorigin` it mentions that this is an animatable attribute? but how is this animatable when it is not actually something that is rendered to the screen or the DOM, the only values that are valid mark-up for `crossorigin` are `anonymous`, `use-credentials` & an empty string.. I know this is a bit of an odd question, but fail to see how you could animated or transition something that has only 3 valid inputs and is not in itself actually a visual feature.. Has anyone seen this or any other notations of this being true? or is it a mistake on the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Animatable" just means that its value can be changed at runtime, and that changing the value alters the behaviour of the element it is attached to.

As used in the standard(s), it isn't specific to graphical animations.

Comment: Does that just mean you can switch it on or off, ie change it value by Javascript or python? still not fully understand...

Comment: In the browser using Javascript.

Comment: & what would be the purpose of switching it at runtime rather than just having it as a static value, which is preset..

Comment: Used on a `<script>` element, perhaps it might not be that useful.  But that attribute is also used on `<img>`, `<audio>`, and `<video` elements, which you may want to change at runtime to point to other files on other different servers..